# Language getting detected but translation not working with i18n

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, internationalization, i18next

I have set up the **i18n** middleware in my Express Node js server like this:

```
// server.js
import i18nMiddleware from 'i18next-express-middleware';
import i18n from 'i18next';
import Backend from 'i18next-node-fs-backend';
import { LanguageDetector } from 'i18next-express-middleware';

i18n
.use(Backend)
.use(LanguageDetector)
.init({
    whitelist: ['en', 'my'],
    fallbackLng: 'en',

    // have a common namespace used around the full app
    ns: ['common'],
    defaultNS: 'common',

    debug: false,

    backend: {
        loadPath: './locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json',
        // jsonIndent: 2
    }
});

app.use(i18nMiddleware.handle(i18n))
```

Here is the translation test file:

```
// test.js
import i18next from "i18next";

const test = (req, res) =>{
    const t = req.i18n.t.bind(i18next);
    
    console.log(req.i18n.language) // language set correctly :)
    console.log(t('title')) // translation not working :(
}
```

The value of title in English is **title** and for Malaysian, it's **tajuk**

As [per the express middleware documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18next-express-middleware#detector-options), I'm passing **my** as the accept-language header , and `console.log(req.i18n.language)` is correctly printing it.

However, `console.log(t('title'))` is still printing **title** instead of **tajuk**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks crazy but this solved the problem:

```
const i18n = req.i18n;
console.log(i18n.t('title'))
```